# IP Tables intercept exception

Tags: iptables, squid, websocket

I've got a set of iptable rules that look like this:

```
-A PREROUTING  --jump intercept-nat
-A intercept-nat --jump DNAT -s 10.10.1.0/24 ! -d 10.10.1.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 --to-destination 10.10.1.1:3126 -m comment --comment "intercept-nat"
-A intercept-nat --jump DNAT -s 10.10.1.0/24 ! -d 10.10.1.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 --to-destination 10.10.1.1:3127 -m comment --comment "intercept-nat"
-A intercept-nat --jump DNAT -s 10.1.2.0/24 ! -d 10.10.1.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 --to-destination 10.10.1.1:3126 -m comment --comment "intercept-nat"
-A intercept-nat --jump DNAT -s 10.1.2.0/24 ! -d 10.10.1.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 --to-destination 10.10.1.1:3127 -m comment --comment "intercept-nat"
```

It's designed to send 80 and 443 traffic to Squid, a http cache proxy. I'd like to put some lines in the iptables rules that would NOT direct 443 traffic to specific IP addresses to 10.10.1.1:3127 (squid)

Use case: I have a websocket server that the clients behind the proxy need to connect to but squid doesnt support websockets. So I want that traffic to bypass squid

Comment: Where is your server with websocket located? On same server?

Comment: Different external server, like websockets.mycompany.com

Comment: Have you tried using the `RETURN` target? Try adding the line `-A PREROUTING -d 10.10.x.x/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j RETURN` before your `--jump intercept-nat` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do the following:

```
-A PREROUTING -s 10.10.1.0/24 ! -d 10.10.1.1/32 --jump intercept-nat
-A PREROUTING -s 10.1.2.0/24 ! -d 10.10.1.1/32 --jump intercept-nat
-A intercept-nat -d target-ip -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j RETURN
-A intercept-nat --jump DNAT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 --to-destination 10.10.1.1:3126 -m comment --comment "intercept-nat"
-A intercept-nat --jump DNAT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 --to-destination 10.10.1.1:3127 -m comment --comment "intercept-nat"
```

Every time a packet destination matches `target-ip` it will skip the rest of the intercept-nat rules. I also changed your rules a little bit to make them more readable and easy to change ;-).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to bypass NAT is to ACCEPT the packet, which will end the path in table (PREROUTING) as well as in chain (intercept-nat). RETURN will leave the chain (intercept-nat) and continue through table (PREROUTING).

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING <some criterium> -j ACCEPT
```

or

```
iptables -t nat -A intercept-nat <some criterium> -j ACCEPT
```

Even though I wrote `-A`, you have to place this line before the NAT action, or insert it in first position.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want to exclude certain traffic from being NATed to your proxy, a rule for that should be placed before the others. And I wouldn't include it in your user-defined chain `intercept-nat` since that chain is logically intended to do NAT, not to not do it.

Simply:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d w.x.y.z -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

where w.x.y.z is the websocket server address.

Besides I would modify your current rules (although I am guessing some things here):

- I think you don't need to specify the source IP addresses in the match section since you probably just want to redirect all traffic from your internal lan(s). I'll assume `eth0` is the external lan and `eth1` and `eth2` the internal ones.
- You probably don't need to specify destination IP address either, saving some CPU cycles. I assume web traffic is not directed to the proxy machine, unless you have a web server running on it.
- If the proxy is running in the same machine as the firewall, you can also avoid to specify the destination IP to use in `DNAT` target by using `REDIRECT` instead.

Eliminating specification of IP addresses improves maintenance, allows reuse and keeps things simpler. All together would be:

```
-A PREROUTING -d w.x.y.z/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING ! -i eth0 -j intercept-nat
-A intercept-nat -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3126 -m comment --comment "intercept-nat"
-A intercept-nat -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3127 -m comment --comment "intercept-nat"
```